# Flurry - Ad recived but sent no ad units

Tags: java, flurry

Ad server responded but sent no ad
units, why I have this error??

This is my code:

```
public class AcercaDe extends Activity implements FlurryAdListener {
    protected static final String TAG = null;
    TextView button;
    FrameLayout mBanner;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.acercade);
    }

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
        FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);
    }
}
```

This is my log:

```
10-20 13:40:03.964: D/FlurryAgent(537): Attempting to persist AdLogs
10-20 13:40:03.964: D/FlurryAgent(537): Attempting to persist FreqCap
10-20 13:40:19.715: E/FlurryAgent(577): Ad server responded but sent no ad units.
10-20 13:49:30.035: D/FlurryAgent(577): Attempting to persist AdLogs
10-20 13:49:30.035: D/FlurryAgent(577): Attempting to persist FreqCap
10-20 13:49:43.614: D/FlurryAgent(616): Attempting to load FreqCap data
10-20 13:49:45.035: E/FlurryAgent(616): Ad server responded but sent no ad units.
10-20 13:50:49.184: D/FlurryAgent(616): Attempting to persist AdLogs
10-20 13:50:49.184: D/FlurryAgent(616): Attempting to persist FreqCap
10-20 13:51:31.664: D/FlurryAgent(655): Attempting to load FreqCap data
```

Can anybody help me??

Comment: Could You format Your code properly, please?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, i try with [CODE][/CODE] but It doesn't work

Comment: More about formatting topic: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Your question isn't helpful and neither it's answer below. Can you add full life cycle integration & methods used to make it more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this issue:
Find interface function shouldDisplayAd() and change return to true :

```
@Override
public boolean shouldDisplayAd(String arg0, FlurryAdType arg1) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where should we find that interface exactly?